# Is it possible to bind a TPM key to a specific application

Tags: linux, security, tpm

I'm just starting to learn about TPMs and was wondering if it's possible to restrict a signing key to a particular application? The idea being that only the application that created the key may use it to encrypt/decrypt data.

I believe there is analogous feature on MacOS that relies on having the application binary signed, and access is enforced by the keychain. Something like this is what I'm trying to mimic

Comment: Do you want to write a driver that encapsulates the key and maps the encrypt/decrypt calls to tpm commands or do you want a method to handle this inside the tpm?

Comment: A think a driver would be fine, mnistic's answer covers the options pretty well I think

Comment: If your application uses a client server approach you can use rsa/ecc signatures to allow access to the key. I would not use pcr registers in applications.

Answer (score 2):

TPM is an input-output device and it does not have a way to somehow reach back to the operating system and verify the application sending the command.

You have a couple of options, neither of which is exactly what you're looking for:

- If you can have your application start as a system service on boot, then you could have the bootloader, or the kernel, measure your application into a PCR and then bind access to the key you want to restrict to that PCR configuration; then once the application has access to the key, it extends the PCR again. This approach guarantees that only your application can access the key, but it requires cooperation from the system firmware, the bootloader and the kernel and is quite complicated, as you will have to deal with PCR fragility going forward -- you will need to rebind access to the key every time any of the components in the system chain of trust change.
- You could protect access to the key with a password, which only your application can provide. Now you have to figure out how to implement access to the password -- whether it's making the user type it in, or communicate with an authenticated service or something else. This approach is much easier to implement, but seems further removed from what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. Certainly a higher barrier to entry than the options available on other platforms